# Could the datastore generate ids that overwrite my entities?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I had a root entity kind that I wanted to refactor to have a parent entity.

These entities all had auto-allocated ids.

I cloned all the existing entities, creating the clone's key from the parent entity and the id of the old entity. Then I deleted the old entities.

Any new entities that get created get auto-allocated ids from the Datastore.

[The docs say:](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids)

> The Datastore's automatic ID allocator never assigns a key belonging to an existing entity to a new entity.

...but I'm not sure if that only applies in the context of pre-allocated ids.

Could my new entities that get created overwrite existing entities?
Or will the Datastore still recognize those ids as already used, despite the parent difference?

Do I have to I pre-allocate all of my existing entity ids to prevent my entities being overwritten by new entities?

Edit:

My old entities had keys like this:

`datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'MyKind', 123456789, _app=u's~my-app')`

My new cloned entities have keys like this (reusing the old id):
`datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'ParentKind', 28882914L, u'MyKind', 123456789, _app=u's~my-app')`

So will the Datastore still think that this id has been used for this kind, despite the fact that the parents are different?

Answer (score 1):

The Datastore will not think that the id has been used. When the Datastore allocates ids, it allocates from a sequence which is determined by the Kind **and** the parent (see the model argument [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids)). Since your new models have a different parent, they will allocate from their own id sequence, which may collide with your manually set id.

Automatically created ids are only guaranteed to not collide with other ids that have been created automatically (using either a `put` with no id set or using the [`allocate_ids`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids) method).

Comment: What will happen if an automatically created id collides with a manually set id?

It doesn't seem that entities will be ever overwritten, so what will happen? The creation of the entity will simply fail?

Comment: In this case the `put` call will fail and the id will be marked as already used.

Comment: Will it fail permanently or will it retry automatically? 

When I try to allocate any of these manually assigned ids using `allocate_id_range` I get the error `Exceeded maximum allocated IDs` on production. In the SDK I got `KEY_RANGE_COLLISION` when I did the same thing.

I guess it's extrememly unlikely that any ids will ever collide if there's a choice of 2**53 ids and the ids are namespaced by Kind and parent, but I'd still like to remove the possibility. Any advice as to what I should do?

Comment: The put itself will fail immediately (depending on the libraries you are using it *might* retry). However, if you call `put` again it will use a new id and succeed. I would recommend (if possible) re-puting your current entities and letting them get new ids, rather than using existing ids. If this isn't an option, I would add your own retry logic.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, the old entities will have the previous ID + the parent ID, correct? And the new entities will also have the parent Id. In this case, Datastore won't overwrite any entity because it never assigns a duplicated key.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the descriptions of the [various possible return values](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/functions#allocate_ids) of `allocate_id_range`, it seems safe to say that the datastore will never overwrite an existing entity with a new entity when using the automatic ID allocator.

[From the SDK:](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#158)

```
KEY_RANGE_EMPTY = "Empty"
"""Indicates the given key range is empty and the datastore's
automatic ID allocator will not assign keys in this range to new
entities.
"""

KEY_RANGE_CONTENTION = "Contention"
"""Indicates the given key range is empty but the datastore's
automatic ID allocator may assign new entities keys in this range.
However it is safe to manually assign keys in this range
if either of the following is true:

 - No other request will insert entities with the same kind and parent
   as the given key range until all entities with manually assigned
   keys from this range have been written.
 - Overwriting entities written by other requests with the same kind
   and parent as the given key range is acceptable.

The datastore's automatic ID allocator will not assign a key to a new
entity that will overwrite an existing entity, so once the range is
populated there will no longer be any contention.
"""

KEY_RANGE_COLLISION = "Collision"
"""Indicates that entities with keys inside the given key range
already exist and writing to this range will overwrite those entities.
Additionally the implications of KEY_RANGE_COLLISION apply. If
overwriting entities that exist in this range is acceptable it is safe
to use the given range.

The datastore's automatic ID allocator will never assign a key to
a new entity that will overwrite an existing entity so entities
written by the user to this range will never be overwritten by
an entity with an automatically assigned key.
"""
```

This other StackOverflow answer agrees: [AppEngine allocateIdRange : clarification about CONTENTION state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9536650/appengine-allocateidrange-clarification-about-contention-state)